# How can I call series of Promise functions?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, async-await, promise

The requirement is finishing the current function before moving to the next call:

```
var current_data = something;
Run(current_data).then((data1) => {
    Run(data1).then(data2 => {
        Run(data2).then(data3 => {
            // and so on
        })
    })
});
```

The example above is only possible if I know exactly how much data I want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the async-await to make code more readable.

```
async function getData(current_data){
  let data1 = await Run(current_data)
  let data2 = await Run(data1);
  let result = await Run(data2);
  return result;  
}
```

Calling the getData function

```
getData(data)
 .then(response => console.log(response))
 .catch(error =>  console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the nested promises part of promise chain, you need to return the nested promises.

```
Run(current_data).then((data1) => {
    return Run(data1).then(data2 => {
        return Run(data2).then .....
    });
});
```

Comment: What are differences between return and not?

Comment: If you do not add return in `then` callback, function creates the promises and return `undefined`. However, if you add `return` it returns the promise and make that promise part of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume your data is paginated and you don't know how many pages there are, therefore you can use a `while` loop with `await` inside of an `async` function like so:

```
(async function() {
  var currentData = someInitialData;
  // loop will break after you've processed all the data
  while (currentData.hasMoreData()) {
    // get next bunch of data & set it as current
    currentData = await Run(currentData);
    // do some processing here or whatever
  }
})();
```

Comment: If my answer solves your problem please click the gray checkmark next to my answer to accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid nested promises. If you need to call a series of promises, which depend on the previous call's response, then you should instead chain then like the following following -

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 1000);
});

promise1.then((response) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(response + ' b');
    }, 1000);
  });

}).then((responseB) => {


  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(responseB + ' c');
    }, 1000);
  });

}).then((responseC) => {

  console.log(responseC); // 'foo b c'
})
```

if your code can support async-await then what Mohammed Ashfaq suggested is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing the same function over and over again but on different data, I would make a recursive function that returns return a Promise.

I just look at my example below using an an array of numbers, you can edit it to your current case.

```js
var current_data = [1,2,4,5,6]

function Run(data){
  if(data.length === 0)
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    //your async operation
    //wait one second before resolving
    setTimeout(()=>{
      data.pop()
      console.log(data)
      resolve(data)
    },1000)
  })
  .then((results)=>{
    return Run(results)
  })
   
}

Run(current_data)
```